# Jquery UI Combobox Functionality in JSF

Tags: jquery-ui, jsf, combobox, richfaces

JSF has autocomplete functionality with enablemanualInput but whenever I try to input a new value which is not present in the dropdown list it turns red and dropdown keeps open to show that no such entry is available. I want to replicate combobox functionality currently present in html/JQUERY UI. Is there any way to do so.

Comment: What component are you using? And what version of RichFaces?

Comment: Hi @Makhiel. Using Mojarra 2.2 in the project.

Comment: That didn't answer either of my questions. What version of RichFaces? And what component?